Show that $Y_n:=\prod_{i=1}^n X_i$ is a Martingale.
I am trying to solve the following exercise:

Let $(X_n)_n$ be independent and identical distributed random
variables that are uniformly distributed on $[0,2]$. Define
$Y_n:=\prod_{i=1}^n X_i$. Show that $(Y_n)_{n\geq 1}$ is a Martingale.

Below is my approach. Let me know if my calculations are correct. Regarding those I have some doubts stated at the end.
Approach:
To show that $(Y_n)$ is a Martingale I need to show that
for all $n$: $E[|Y_n|]< \infty$ and $E[Y_{n+1}|\mathcal{F}_n]=Y_n$.
$E[|Y_n|]=E[|\prod_{i=1}^n X_i|]\leq \prod_{i=1}^{n} E[|X_i|]=1$.
Let $\mathcal{F}_n:=\sigma(Y_0,Y_1,...,Y_n)$.
$E[Y_{n+1}|\mathcal{F}_n]=E[X_{n+1}Y_n|\mathcal{F}_n]$.
Fix $n$, then $Y_n$ is bounded and $\mathcal{F}_n$ measurable. Thus $E[X_{n+1}Y_n|\mathcal{F}_n]=Y_nE[X_{n+1}|\mathcal{F}_n]$.
Now since $X_{n+1}$ is independent of $\mathcal{F}_n$, $E[X_{n+1}|\mathcal{F}_n]=E[X_{n+1}]=1$.
Thus $E[Y_{n+1}|\mathcal{F}_n]=Y_n$.
My thoughts:
I used two properties of the conditional expectation w.r.t $\sigma$ algebras.

If $Y$ is bounded and $\mathcal{F} $measurable, then $E[XY|\mathcal{F}]=YE[X|\mathcal{F}]$.
And $Y_n$ as a product of bounded (uniform on $[0,2]$) random variables is obviously bounded.
I am unsure on why $Y_n$ is $\mathcal{F}_n$ measurable. I know that $\mathcal{F}_n:=\sigma(Y_1,Y_2,...,Y_n)$. But I do not know how $\sigma(Y_1,Y_2,...,Y_n)$ is defined.
What I do know is the definition of a $\sigma$-algebra generated by one random variable, for example for some r.v. Z I know what $\sigma(Z)$ means. But I do not know what $\sigma(Y_1,Y_2,...,Y_n)$ would be.
I assume that $\sigma(Y_n) \subset \sigma(Y_1,Y_2,...,Y_n)$ and thus $Y_n$ should also be $\sigma(Y_1,Y_2,...,Y_n)$ measurable.

Further I used that $X_{n+1}$ is independent of $\mathcal{F_n}$, or I rather assume that $X_{n+1}$ is independent of $\mathcal{F_n}$.
Here I thought that since $\mathcal{F_n}=\sigma(Y_1,Y_2,...,Y_n)=\sigma(X_1,X_1 X_2,...,X_1 \cdot \cdot \cdot X_n)$ and since $X_{n+1}$ is independent of $\prod_{i=1}^k X_i$ for every $k=1,...,n$, the $\sigma$ algebra generated by those and $X_{n+1} should be independent$.


To me both argumentations seem a little bit hand wavy. My main concern is the uncertainty on how $\sigma(Y_1,...,Y_n)$ is defined.

The random vector $Y_1, \ldots, Y_n$ is a map $(Y_1, \ldots, Y_n): \Omega \to \mathbb{R}^n$. The sigma algebra $\sigma(Y_1, \ldots, Y_n)$ is the smallest sigma algebra containing the preimages of Borel sets $B \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ under this map.

I think you are making it more complicated than it needs to be. All you want to show is that $E(Y_{n} | X_{0}, X_{1}, \ldots X_{n-1}) = Y_{n-1}$.

Note that $X_{0}, X_{1}, \ldots, X_{n-1}$ in above can be replaced with $\mathcal{F}_{n-1}$.

@markleeds I didn't know/think of replacing $X_0,X_1,...,X_{n-1} with \mathcal{F}_{n-1}$. Thank you for the hint. But I do not see why it would be allowed the do this replacement. (Sorry if this is something obvious, I am fairly new to probability.)

In that whole post it is again unclear whether $n$ starts from $1$ or $0,.$ Hint to your last comment: the information you have in $X_1,\dots,X_n$ is the same as that you have in $Y_1,\dots,Y_n,.$ Why? You can algebraically convert between both. $X_1=Y_1$ hence you know $X_2$ when I give you $Y_2=X_1X_2$ and so on.

@KurtG. Sorry for the unclarity, $n$ starts with $1$. I do not see how I can convert between those two.

@NTc5: I'm not a mathematician so I hope that they explain why you can replace the set of previous ${X_i}$ with $\mathcal{F}{n-1}$. I think of $\mathcal{F}{n-1}$ as consisting of all the information provided by the process upto and including time $(n-1)$. Definitely, the whole past of $X$ also contains all the imformation provided by the process upto and including time $(n-1)$ So this is my answer as to why it's okay to do that replacement I'm certain there are better answers.

Let's take $n=2,.$ I hope you can convert $X_1,X_2$ to $Y_1,Y_2,.$ Conversely, set $X_1=Y_1$ and $X_2=Y_2/Y_1,.$ I leave it to you to think about the case $Y_1=0,.$

@KurtG. Oh I see. Thank you for the help. Regarding that, I do see now that $X_1,...,X_n$ and $Y_1,...,Y_n $gives the same "Information". But I do not really get what "Information" should mean. On other posts I saw that the sigma algebra $\mathcal{F}$ would be mentioned as Information. But I am not completly sure what exactly is meant with that.

If I type \sigma algebra information is:question into the search field of MSE I get 268 hits. Pick your favourite and read.
